# Launch Google Maps with location via Cordova

Tags: java, android, google-maps, cordova

In Cordova, I'm trying to build a map to find camping areas, but I can't manage google maps in order to toggle navigation.

I found a plugin which allows me to open any application I want, but I can't pass it any parameter other than its package name. Here's what I've written so far:

```
    package technology.kulak.cordova.appopen;
    import org.apache.cordova.CordovaPlugin;
    import org.apache.cordova.CallbackContext;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
    import org.json.JSONArray;
    import org.json.JSONException;
    import org.json.JSONObject;
    import android.util.Log;
    public class OpenApplication extends CordovaPlugin {
        @Override
        public boolean execute(String action, JSONArray args, CallbackContext callbackContext) throws JSONException {
            Log.d("kulak", "EXECUTING");
            Context context = this.cordova.getActivity().getApplicationContext();
            Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
            PackageManager manager = context.getPackageManager();
            i = manager.getLaunchIntentForPackage(action);
            i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
            context.startActivity(i);
            return true;
        }
    }
```

As you can see, I have access to the action parameter, but nothing else. How should I go about passing a parameter while opening another application?